# Stored procedures for reading a file name and create a table

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, vbscript, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to read a file name of a CSV file in a folder.

```
D:\folder
└─Jan_14_john_998754.csv
```

and create a MySQL table from its name `john_998754`.

Is this possible in stored procedures? If possible, how should I implement this in Visual Basic?

Comment: first time using stored procedures so currently have minimum knowledge, but theoretically what I can think of is read in folder and search filename, and save it into a variable and concatenate into three pieces, add second and third part and assign it into a variable. Finally, use sql statement like CREATE with the variable? But I mean, can sql statement be used in visual basic?

Comment: Without some actual code to narrow down the question this question is just too broad, especially when you couple that with *"can sql statement be used in visual basic?"*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is possible as a MySQL query, which you can put in your stored procedure.
here is the query.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'path_to_csv/the_csv_file_name.csv' INTO TABLE the_table_name
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
```